# "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow

```
DateTime tThen = DateTime.Now;
do
{
    Application.DoEvents();
} while (!cefGlueBrowserForm.Done || tThen.AddSeconds(15) > DateTime.Now);

string htmlSource = cefGlueBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml;
propertyBag.GetResponse = () => new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlSource));
cefGlueBrowserForm.Dispose();
```

After few hours I get in line

```
while (!cefGlueBrowserForm.Done || tThen.AddSeconds(15) > DateTime.Now);
```

exception of

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Here is description of error:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6sxk224%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

> Too many method calls is often indicative of a very deep or unbounded recursion.

so what Can I do? I need to wait until some code in cefGlueBrowserForm is finished or time is reached. But why then error, I have time check...

Comment: Your condition in || won't be checked. If first condition is true.

Comment: Please don't delete [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731211/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-stackoverflowexception-occurred-in-syste) just to re-post it.

Comment: Have a look at the callstack!

Comment: @Mohammad you are right. || is wrong. and I also need CompareTo for comparing dates and not simle >

Comment: I am right `||` is wrong. Sounds pretty fun.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)

> The conditional-OR operator (||) performs a logical-OR of its bool operands. If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated.

Your second condition in `||` won't be checked if first condition is true.

This program illustrates the concept

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( p() || q() ); //prints Return True from p , True
        Console.WriteLine( q() || p() ); //prints Return False from q, Return true from p, True
    }

    static bool p()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Return True");
        return true;
    }

    static bool q()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Return False");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant, as the second condition in the question has no side effects. Edit: Actually, I might be completely misunderstanding the point of your answer. Downvote removed for now, but would you elaborate? The point stands, the condition in the question is free of side effects.

Comment: "But why then error, I have time check..."  I suppose that time check isn't any good if that isn't being checked

Comment: Ah, now I see your point, which is essentially "you want `&&`, not `||`". That's not clear from your answer, but you're right. Note that if you use `|` instead of `||`, where the second operand would be evaluated, you'd still have the same problem.

Comment: How do you think is this related to StackOverlow exception?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit clearer, thanks for that. I still think you're focusing on the wrong aspect, though, because even if the second operand of `||` were evaluated, the code wouldn't work as intended.

Comment: My answer was based on "infinite loop" assumption. if `cefGlueBrowserForm.Done` happens to be `false`, then don't we have an infinite loop there ?

Answer (score 1):

`Application.DoEvents` is evil, don't use that. It may cause unexplainable effects - like StackOverflow. Busy-waiting in the UI thread should be avoided. To fix it use, eg, `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Why BackgroundWorker if I just need to wait? I don't need to BackgroundWorker process just for waiting. Or do I?

Comment: You obviously use `Application.DoEvents` to prevent blocking the GUI thread. The right way to do it, is to move the blocking part to a background thread. If you can use .Net Framework 4.5 it could be easier to use async/await, though.

Comment: Sorry - that's too wide a subject. Also I don't know enough about your project. Just search for "c# async await" to find a wealth of information and examples. Re DoEvents see for example http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents